# How to add a color gradient to a picture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gimp, gradient, color-reproduction

I felt in love with the way this graphic designer, called Mariusz, has edited this picture.

It would be fun to produce something like this for myself.

Anyone has some ideas on how to create such a nice color effect in Photoshop or Gimp?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### For Photoshop:

Starting with the source image in greyscale:

[image: http://everysinglepixel.com/]
<sup>Source: http://everysinglepixel.com</sup>

Add a layer with a gradient fill on top of it, adjust the blending mode for the layer to something that looks nice. I chose Soft Light and tweaked the opacity.

[image: Gradient]

Comment: My mental vote for the nobel prize goes to you next year. Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 9):

I say: Don't start with a greyscale image!

Use the layer effect "Gradient Overlay" with the blend mode "Color". That way you can keep the  color information and add some depth by using only i.e. 50% opacity of the effect.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

### For Gimp:

These are the steps I took using GIMP to create a color gradient on the [source image](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/18494/12941).

- Choose the **Blend** tool to fill with a color gradient.

  [image]
- Create a **new gradient** with desired colors (Left HSV 21,83,91, Right HSV 301,52,60)
- Apply the Blend tool in **Mode - Overlay** along a line from left to right:

  [image]
- Blend mode **Color** for a stronger effect:

  [image]