# How to apply color layout to an image?

Tags: gimp

Is there a way to in GIMP to apply a color layout to an image?

For example this image has a blue color laid out on it. How can I do something similar to another image?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can improve your question by showing us what you have tried so far that hasn't worked or listing the terms that you have searched for prior to posting a question here.

Comment: @JohnB Hi, I'm new to gimp and don't even know what terms to search on google for this I tried "how to layout color on top of image" however, most of what I found was how to change background color of an image.

Comment: try searching for 'colour overlay' or 'gradient overlay'. [This question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33690/how-to-colorize-an-image-as-in-the-example) might help.

Comment: actually I tried "toggle quick mask" but it just lays out a red mask. I can't seem to change its color

Comment: Also see [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18493/how-to-add-a-color-gradient-to-a-picture) using another source but the procedures are the same.

Comment: I downvoted your question because i see no effort or attempt in trying to do what you're asking.  If you would [edit] your question with an attempt after vincent and takkat gave some similar links to follow and even if you still failed i would give you an upvote for effort but at this time it would appear you are looking for a tutorial

Answer (score 2):

In GIMP or any other Image editing program, the easiest way is to use Layers for this kind of thing. Check GIMP's initial documentation on Layers here:
http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-layers.html

The basic concept is that each image, when open in GIMP behaves not only as a printed image on paper, but as a stack of several transparent films, the bottommost of which is your "background". By pressing `ctrl + L` in GIMP, you will focus the Layers dialog - just click on the New Layer icon there, choose "transparent layer" - you can  now draw over your original image, without affecting its contents. There is an "Opacity" slider where you can make it partially transparent and have an effect similar to above.

Play around, and see the documentation (on layer modes, and such) to get the best results for you.